# Symfony 2.8 application truble

Tags: php, symfony

i've a problem with an application created with symfony 2.8.
I use symfony 5.2 but i have to do some improvement in an application builded whith symfony 2.8(not mine).
I've tried to install symfony 2.8 but is deprecated and don't work.
I have 5 directories of 2.8 project :

1. vendor
2. app
3. src
4. doc
5. bin

i create a project

```
symfony new my_project_name
```

then i paste the 5 directories and doesen't work.
i've tried use parameter --version=2.8  but  nothing...

Any suggestion ? thanks in advance.

Comment: There are missing folders like `web`. I installed a 2.8 version of symfony with the command `composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition labo2.8 "2.8.*"`. Do you have the original composer.json ? What's not working ?

Comment: when i go to the page i see that error :
'''You are not allowed to access this file. Check app_dev.php for more information.'''

Comment: You have to check app_dev.php for more informations. There is an array of allowed ip's to execute the file. How is your localhost configured ?

Comment: ok i modified the app_dev and i insert my ip in th IF istruction.
but now the error is :
ClassNotFoundException in AppKernel.php line 27:
Attempted to load class "UserBundle" from namespace "UserBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
I try to use :
symfony require UserBundle .... but it dosen't work

Comment: This is a complete new issue, I suggest you to close this question and ask another with fragments of your code.